# How do I move my mouse to coordinates stored in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, mouse, draw

Uhm hi,
I am pretty new to programming and have just started a project in python. I am trying to make a program that draws a given image onto a canvas with a fixed palette using dithering (for skribbl.io). My idea was to scan the dithered image for every color and put the coordinates into arrays. The color arrays are then put in another array.
Then I wanted to use the mouse module to simulate clicks on the coords.

```
def getcoords():
img = cv2.imread("img_dither.png")
color = [palettedata[a], palettedata[a + 1], palettedata[a + 2]]
blue = color[0]
green = color[1]
red = color[2]
x,y,z = img.shape
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if img[i, j, 0] == blue & img[i, j, 1] == green & img[i, j, 1] == red:
            pixels[v].append(2*i + 370) # offset of the canvas = 370, 180
            pixels[v].append(2*j + 180) # times 2 because the smallest brush size of skribbl is 2*2 pixels

length = len(palettedata)
a = 0
v = 0

while a < length:
    getcoords()
    a += 3
    v += 1
```

that part worked fine but when I tried to click on the coords with:

```
def draw():
    b = 0
    c = 0
    while b < len(pixels):
        while c < len(pixels[b]):
            mouse.move(pixels[b[c]], pixels[b[c+1]], absolute=True, duration=0) # supposed to move to the first entry of pixels which is pixelsBlack[] and there to the first entry for x and the 2nd for y, pixelsBlack has a form of [x, y, x, y, ...]
            mouse.click(button='left')
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): # Failsafe
                break
            c += 2
        b += 1
        c = 0
```

I got the error:
`line 132, in draw mouse.move(pixels[b[c]], pixels[b[c+1]], absolute=True, duration=0) TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
and I dont understand whats wrong...
(This is also my first time here on stackoverflow btw)

Comment: What are you expecting to get with `b[c]`?

Comment: The first x coordinate of the first color.

Comment: But both b and c are numbers. You are effectively trying to do `0[0]`. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you are trying to get value of 2D array, you should do `pixels[b][c]`

Comment: well thanks this solved it, I didnt know that

Comment: Makes sense, really. `pixels` is a 2D array, `pixels[b]` is 1d array, and you treat this array like usual - by adding `[c]` at the end to get element at specific index.